# Download all source code files through SFTP

Tags: sftp, mask, batch-processing

I need to back up all the code from a server onto a local machine. By code I mean any text-based file (.php, .js, .html, etc). The server contains over 300GB of various media (.ogg, .mov, .mp4, .pdf, etc) which I do not want to download.

I am trying to use WinSCP to download only the desired files, but its not working. I set an "Input Mask", but all files are being downloaded anyway.

[image]

I would really appreciate some suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory in. In this case since it seems you want them from every directory, you would change your mask to `*/*.*html; */*.htm`, etc.

Comment: I changed the filter to Include only `*/*.*php` but I got "File "/var/www" excluded from transfer"